# How do I type a React ref accessing a DOM element from an array

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

Let's say I want to get access to the last element in an array of JSX elements.

```js
let array = [
  <button type="button" />,
  <button type="button" />,
  <button type="button" />,
];

let last = array[array.length - 1];
```

The type inference works here fine.

But now let's say I want to attach a ref to the last element in that array.

```js
let last = React.useRef<HTMLButtonElement>();

let array = [
  <button type="button" />,
  <button type="button" />,
  <button type="button" />,
];

last.current = array[array.length - 1];
```

The above snippet results in this error.

```
Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLButtonElement':
disabled, form, formAction, formEnctype, and 249 more.
```

I thought maybe I needed to explicitly type `array: HTMLButtonElement[]`, but that just moves the error to the array declaration.

Changing the ref type to `React.useRef<JSX.Element>` will remove the error, but loses the specificity of ensuring its a button element.

Comment: Double check the docs to make sure you are using refs correctly: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html (the examples in the docs and the example you gave are very different). Note also that JSX elements and DOM elements are _not_ the same thing. `ref.current` needs a DOM element, but your array contains JSX element (the results of `React.createElement('button'…)`), so they don't match.

Comment: After render, each JSX element will have a matching DOM element, and refs are what you use to get that matching DOM element.

Comment: Also, why do you need refs? are you doing something specific with DOM elements?

Comment: Ah, that was my bad for creating an example conflating DOM and JSX elements. I did that to simplify the issue I was having but created a new issue in the wake . Changing the example to use `document.createElement('button')` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question example conflates DOM and JSX elements. I used `<button>` JSX elements in the array to simplify the issue I was having, but mistakenly created a new issue in the wake.

Creating DOM elements instead of JSX elements works.

```js
let last = React.useRef<HTMLButtonElement>();

let array = [
  document.createElement('button'),
  document.createElement('button'),
  document.createElement('button'),
];

last.current = array[array.length - 1];
```

We can also get the array of DOM elements by querying for them on the page (which is what my actual situation involved).

```js
let array = document.querySelectorAll<HTMLButtonElement>('button');
```

Answer (score 0):

in your example, you can just set up your ref as the property to the last element:

```
let last = React.useRef<Partial<HTMLButtonElement>|null>(null);
let array = [
  <button type="button" />,
  <button type="button" />,
  <button type="button" ref={last} />,
];
```

But I'm assuming this example is simplified, and that won't work for your actual use case...

Comment: Right, yeah, let's imagine the elements are coming from somewhere else, are dynamically added/changed, are composite components, etc.